# Twitter Reauthentication

Tags: android, twitter

I have developed one app in which there is option for sharing on twitter.Its working properly fine.Now one requirement came which says that if the app is force killed it should again ask for authentication with twitter so that we can give user id and password again.The main thing is if user want to login to twitter with his new credentials how he will do that.Any idea how to solve this issue.Right now if i am uninstalling the app or clearing the data it is doing authentication but it should do on force killing the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect your app being force killed: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/xfkfRc-j4cw

It might be possible to set a flag when your app starts, and clear the flag when your app stops in an orderly way. If the flag is set when your app is starting, then you know it was last stopped in a disorderly way, like being force killed. This method of detection will probably give you both false positives (if someone pulls the battery out of their phone, your flag will probably still be set) and false negatives (if your app considers itself to have been stopped in an orderly way, and is then force killed). This method will surely give you angst and tears unto the fifth generation. Here be dragons, and the dragons will eat you.

You should push back against the requirement.

Comment: First thing is how we will know the app is disorderly stopped.If we detect that also how re authentication to twitter will happen because its an automated process.

Comment: The point is that you really can't detect your app being force killed. It's a fool's errand.

Comment: Is there any way we will be able to clear data of our app if app is force killed? I need urgent help on this.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, you can clear your tokens when the app starts again, in an `onStart();` method for example. So next time the user will use the application after the forced kill, this last wouldn't get any access tokens to work properly and would be consequently "forced" to ask tokens again via a classic OAuth Authentication Flow.

Reauthentications are just like classic authentications. At the end, the Twitter API will give you back the missed (or deleted) access tokens.